# SQLAlchemy - How to select cerain rows?

Tags: python, select, sqlalchemy

How to simulate a `SELECT` in `SQLAlchemy`? I would like to create a function which takes a couple of parameters and returns a row which contains those values but I can't do `SELECT`.

The only way I found is below but I can't find `metadata` in `SQLAlchemy` module.

EDIT: I figured out that `BoundMetaData` is deprecated so `MetaData` is appropriate, but it says that `Select has no len`

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import Column, Table
from sqlalchemy import UniqueConstraint
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.exc import IntegrityError
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///db.db', echo=False)
Base = declarative_base()

s = sqlalchemy.orm.Session(engine)


class Flight(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'flights'

    id = Column(sqlalchemy.Integer, primary_key=True)
    destination_from = Column(sqlalchemy.String)
    destination_to = Column(sqlalchemy.String)
    creation_date = Column(sqlalchemy.Date)
    start_date = Column(sqlalchemy.Date)
    return_date = Column(sqlalchemy.Date)
    price = Column(sqlalchemy.Float)
    filename = Column(sqlalchemy.String)
    bought_days_before = Column(sqlalchemy.Integer)

    __table_args__ = (
        UniqueConstraint('creation_date', 'destination_from', 'destination_to', 'start_date', 'return_date', 'price'),
    )


Base.metadata.create_all(engine)


def insert_into_flights(**kwargs):
    s.add(Flight(**kwargs))
    try:
        s.commit()
    except IntegrityError as e:
        s.rollback()


def get_prices(date_from, days, bought_days_before, destination, min=True, avg=False):
    flights = Table('flights', metadata ,autoload=True
                )
    print len(flights.select())
```

Comment: What do you mean by "simulate"? For what purpose are you trying to "simulate"?

Comment: Just wrong word. I wanted to do SELECT as Jesse Baker answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
s.query(Flight).filter(Flight.id==34).all()
```

This is an example selecting the Flight with id 34.
See [SQLAlchemy docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/tutorial.html#querying)